# Regional decimal seperator input

Tags: c#, decimal, cultureinfo, region

Computers in my country do not accept decimals with a '.' they only accept ','

How do I write a program which would accept 12.5 from the console as a decimal number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `CultureInfo`. If you are sure that using decimal dot is a standard in your country then use your country's `CultureInfo`. You can simply check if it is.

```
// Change kk-KZ to your culture code
decimal dec = decimal.Parse(str, new CultureInfo("kk-KZ"));
```

Or you can use `InvariantCulture` and `NumberStyles.Any`:

```
decimal dec = decimal.Parse(str, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I will implement the second one as I don't know where you are from.
Here it is in an console application and it works for me:

```
public static void Main()
{
    string str;

    str = Console.ReadLine();

    decimal dec = decimal.Parse(str, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    double db = double.Parse(str, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    Console.WriteLine(dec.ToString("F2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    Console.WriteLine(db.ToString("F2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

    return;
}
```

Comment: I want to write 12.5 into the console and have it be interpreted as a decimal.

Comment: Look at the updated answer. That's how you parse decimal-dot-separated `decimal` \ `double` from a string, inputed in a console.